# Unable to parse JSON array with son simple

Tags: java, json

ANYTIME I try to parse a file containing a JSON Array with JSON Simple, I end up getting this error message ... code always seems fine in examples but I still get this EVERYTIME I try something ! . please help !

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: 

class org.json.simple.JSONObject cannot be cast to class java.lang.String (org.json.simple.JSONObject is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; 
java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
```

an example of an example from this site that still didn't work

```
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
        //Parsing the contents of the JSON file
        try (Reader reader = new FileReader("example-member-list.json")) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(new FileReader("example-member-list.json"));
            JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("members");               
            //Iterating the contents of the array
            Iterator<String> iterator = jsonArray.iterator();
            while(iterator.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(iterator.next());
            }


        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with this line.

```
Iterator<String> iterator = jsonArray.iterator();
```

JSONArray iterator returns JsonObject Iterator.

Change the above line to

```
Iterator<JSONObject> iterator = jsonArray.iterator();
```

Please note that json-simple is not actively maintained. So if you are learning about JSON parsing, I would suggest to check out Google's GSON library (link below).

https://github.com/google/gson